# UploadingItemAdapter gives LogCat null value and listItem's text views are also remains blank in fragment of listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I don't know in which part i made mistake. In `UploadItemAdapter.class,uploadingDetails.getTitle()` and `uploadingDetails.getDiscription()` both gives me null in my log cat. In android listView screen textView of item is also remains blank [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kmix.png) .My Computer [Screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAiVB.png)
My code is mentioned below.
*UploadItemAdapter.java*

```
package com.example.shiva.gconnection.extendedVersion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.shiva.gconnection.R;
import com.example.shiva.gconnection.UploadingDetails;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by shiva on 3/3/18.
 */

public class UploadItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UploadingDetails>{
    public UploadItemAdapter( Context context, int resource, List<UploadingDetails> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position ,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((FragmentActivity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.uploaded_material_child, parent, false);
        }
        TextView titalTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_item_upload_material);
        TextView discriptionTV= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discription_item_upload_material);

        UploadingDetails uploadingDetails = getItem(position);
        titalTV.setText(uploadingDetails.getTitle());
        discriptionTV.setText(uploadingDetails.getDiscription());
        Log.v("abcd",uploadingDetails.getTitle() +" "+uploadingDetails.getDiscription());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

*uploaded_material.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_upload_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/uploaded_material_child" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*Uploaded_material_child.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/title_item_upload_material"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Discription"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/discription_item_upload_material"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UploadedBy"
        android:id="@+id/uploaded_by"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*FragmentLastView.java*

```
package com.example.shiva.gconnection.extendedVersion;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.shiva.gconnection.R;
import com.example.shiva.gconnection.UploadingDetails;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FragmentLastView extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseDatabase mdatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mdbRef;
    private ListView mItemLV;
    private ChildEventListener childEventListener;
    private ArrayAdapter mUploadItemAdapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.uploaded_material,container,false);
        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mdbRef = mdatabase.getReference("College");
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final String subjectName = getArguments().getString("SubjectName");
        final String branchname = getArguments().getString("BranchName");
        final String class1Name = getArguments().getString("Class1Name");
        final String className = getArguments().getString("ClassName");

        final ArrayList<UploadingDetails> uploadingDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        mItemLV= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_upload_item);

        mUploadItemAdapter = new UploadItemAdapter(view.getContext(),R.layout.uploaded_material_child,uploadingDetails);
        mItemLV.setAdapter(mUploadItemAdapter);

        childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                UploadingDetails updetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(UploadingDetails.class);
                uploadingDetails.add(updetails);
                mUploadItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        mdbRef.child(branchname).child(subjectName).child(className).child(class1Name).addChildEventListener(childEventListener);


    }
}
```

*UploadingDetails.java*

```
package com.example.shiva.gconnection;

    public class UploadingDetails {
        private String mTitle;
        private String mDiscription;
        private String mArrayUri;

        public UploadingDetails(){
        }

        public UploadingDetails(String title, String discription,String arrayUri){
            this.mTitle= title;
            this.mDiscription=discription;
            this.mArrayUri=arrayUri;

        }

        public String getTitle(){
            return this.mTitle;
        }

        public String getDiscription(){
            return this.mDiscription;
        }

        public String getArrayUri(){return this.mArrayUri;}
    }
```

Comment: Code dumps are generally unhelpful.  Please post a succinct example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for .....???

Comment: You should not just dump large amounts of code in your question.  Post the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: onChildAdded is there data coming accurately ??

Comment: I think everyThing i posted will need for reproduce the problem..... i am beginner in android. I can't  find in which part i have problem. even my logCat is not showing me error. my application is not crashing. i stuck with part...... i tried a lot to figure problem. please check above sceenshot of my android and pc screen perhaps it will help you for answering.

Comment: yes sir dataSnapshot.toString() in logCat gives me the object. thats ok...

Comment: may be you are right sir... there is problem with onChildAdded....data is comming accurately but its not storing in the variable which is diclared as class i tried following code which gives error ... mItemLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                UploadingDetails upd = uploadingDetails.get(position);
                Log.v("abcd",upd.getTitle());
            }
        });

Comment: Please use [`FirebaseListAdapter`](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html) instead of `ArrayAdapter` in `UploadItemAdapter`. Firebase SDK automatically handles data change. Take advantage of that.

Comment: when i tried `Log.v("abcd", String.valueOf(uploadingDetails.size()));`  in FragmentLastView.java gives me zero value each time whether there is data or not.

Comment: when i put `Log.v("abcd", String.valueOf(uploadingDetails.size()));` inside onChildadded Method it gives me the exact size of uploadingDetails ArrayList

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't understand how it worked but when i changed following code problem was solved 
*UploadindDetils.java*

```
package com.example.shiva.gconnection;

public class UploadingDetails {
    private String mTitle;
    private String mDiscription;
    private String mArrayUri;

    public UploadingDetails() {
    }

    public UploadingDetails(String title, String discription, String arrayUri) {
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mDiscription = discription;
        this.mArrayUri = arrayUri;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.mTitle;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this. mTitle = title;
    }

    public void setDiscription(String discription) {
        this.mDiscription = discription;
    }

    public void setArrayUri(String arrayUri) {
        this.mArrayUri = arrayUri;
    }

    public String getDiscription() {
        return this.mDiscription;
    }

    public String getArrayUri() {
        return this.mArrayUri;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the fields in your model class must much to the name of the data on witch your want retrieve in firebase data reference node